# What are the advantages of viewset over apiview in django rest framework?

Tags: rest, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

Differences between viewset and apiview in django rest framework.

Comment: i don't this is right plateform to ask this questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

viewset comes with already implemented all method and extra action, for the APiview you have to define all method

Answer (score 0):

If you have built MVC before, you may find it easier to build out your models using APIView. For the explicit use of '*CRUD*' methods. I would suggest being consistent with where/how you use them as well, especially if someone else has to look at/work on the project, and is less familiar with Django.